# prompt box shown only once for same bind variable

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I create a plsql loop that prompt the user to enter a value into a bind variable, the prompt code written inside the loop so that the user can re-enter the value if the previous input is rejected.
the problem is that the prompt box message shown only at first time, after that the loop use the same value entered at first. how to allow the user to enter the value again and again until it's accepted.
follwoing an snippt of my code. it's executed on sql developer:

```
accept v_input_value prompt 'enter value: ';
DECLARE
  value_in number := &v_input_value;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    -- Prompt the user for input value
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Enter a value: ');
    -- Check if the input value is accepted
    IF value_in = 3 THEN
      -- Value is accepted, exit the loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value is accepted, exit the loop.');
      EXIT;
    ELSE
      -- Value is not accepted, prompt for a new value
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid value. Please try again.');
       value_in := &v_input_value;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  -- Print the accepted value
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Accepted value: ' || value_in);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Substitution (not bind) variables like `&v_input_value` are evaluated once, when the PL/SQL block is prepared for compilation by the client - not as it is being executed.

The variable is not, and cannot be, re-evaluated or re-promoted within the PL/SQL block. The block is executed as a single unit within the database - once it has been submitted for compilation and execution it is independent of the client, which just waits for it to complete (unless you interrupt it, which the client also handles). PL/SQL is not an interactive language, and you shouldn't confuse client functionality (e.g. substitution variables) with SQL or PL/SQL functionality.

If you [`set verify on`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-74CA1665-165D-4C0D-BBB2-681BD3485211) before running your script you will see the 'before' and 'after' text for your entire PL/SQL block, with the user-entered value embedded in the 'after' version, before that is sent to the database. That then doesn't change, and is all the database sees.

---

Your example is a bit contrived, as there's no point prompting for a single specific value. If you had a range of allowed values you could include a check for that in a query and return no results if the supplied value isn't allowed. Or you could have an anonymous block that throws an exception if the value isn't expected. Neither allows you to re-prompt though. (A wrapper shell script would, but that's getting a bit off-topic...)

If your real scenario is a bit less contrived and you wanted to test for, say, a single digit number then you could change your [`accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/ACCEPT.html):

```
accept v_input_value number format '9' prompt 'enter value: ';
```

but it depends what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: I would have said that the substitution variable was handled on the client before it is even passed to the database and the database compiles the code. The database will not see the substitution variable (and if you did pass a substitution variable to the database in, for example, an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement then the database would raise a syntax error as it does not understand it [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vzc1YKsj))

Comment: Yes... I suppose I see it as part of the process of compiling it, but agree it's the client doing that work, not the DB. I've rephrased it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A substitution variable is evaluated by the client application (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, SQLCl or other clients that support substitution variables). It is **NOT** supported by Oracle databases.

When the client application reads the statement it sees the substitution variable and asks you, the user, what value the substitution variable should have and then effectively does a find-replace and substitutes all the instances of that substitution variable with the value you have supplied and then sends the modified query to the database which runs it.

The database **NEVER** sees the substitution variable and is not involved in asking for user input (and has no mechanism that would allow it to ask for user input).

Therefore, when the query is run in the database there will be no substitution variables in the query (and if there were then the database would not understand them [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vzc1YKsj)) so whatever the first value of the substitution variable is will be the value that is always there.

> how to allow the user to enter the value again and again until it's accepted.

You cannot, SQL and PL/SQL do not work like that.

The client can ask for user input before it sends the query to the database but the database has no mechanism to ask for user input when it is running the statement.